# React: how do I get rid of this Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a component that has a state which is an object, and I wanted to set the state in an `useEffect` where it loops through the keys of the object to update the state. The problem is that it gives me an error for infinite loops.

> Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops.

I figured that it is because the list of keys I am using as the `dep` of the `useEffect` is an array and that is different every time the component re-renders because it is not a primitive type. So I memo’ed it using `useMemo` but it still doesn’t work then I realized that it might be because the memo’s `dep` is the state, which is also NOT a primitive type, i.e. an object so it is different every time that results in the list of keys being different every time even with `useMemo`

Here is the code

```
const ManageIndexingPage: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const stateFromStore = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.settings.indexing
  );
  const [indexingConfig, setIndexingConfig] = useState<IndexingConfig>(
    getDefaultIndexingConfig()
  );

  const listOfKeys = useMemo(
    () => Object.keys(indexingConfig) as Array<keyof typeof indexingConfig>,
    [indexingConfig]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getIndexingConfig());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    listOfKeys.forEach((key) =>
      setIndexingConfig((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [key]: stateFromStore[key]
      }))
    );
  }, [stateFromStore, listOfKeys]);
};

//....

function getDefaultIndexingConfig(): IndexingConfig {
  return {
    thingIndexingEnabled: false,
    thingConnectivityEnabled: false,
    thingDeviceShadowEnabled: false,
    thingGroupIndexingEnabled: false
  };
}
```

Here `listOfkeys` is really just an array of strings i.e. `["thingIndexingEnabled", "thingConnectivityEnabled"...]`. So if I hardcoded it and use that in `useEffect` there wouldn't have this error and it's fine
i.e.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ["thingIndexingEnabled", "thingConnectivityEnabled"...].forEach((key) =>
      setIndexingConfig((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [key]: stateFromStore[key]
      }))
    );
  }, [stateFromStore]);
```

How should I get rid of this error without hardcoding the list of keys? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   ....
      setIndexingConfig((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [key]: stateFromStore[key]
      }))
    );
  }, [stateFromStore, listOfKeys]);
```

You should not setState in `useEffect()` because it is dependent on that an every change will cause the useEffect to reexecute again.
setThe state from another place or use useRef, as it doesnt cause rerender.

Comment: this is not true. using `setState` in `useEffect` is not necessarily going to case an infinite loop, as long as the state that is being state is not part of the deps of the `useEffect`

Comment: I said that this is caused because the effect has deps that are updated in setState